# Instagram Custom URL Scheme Not Working in iOS12

Tags: instagram

We pass an image from our app to Instagram using their standard iPhone URL scheme. It was working fine in iOS11, but in iOS12 it briefly goes to an Instagram login page (even though we're logged in) and then opens the Instagram Library with our image and tapping next to the Share screen places the image on a share page with many options unavailable. For example if you type a # hashtag it does no lookup. Tapping share does nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: were you able to find any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The redirect to the login page is a bug with the Instagram app, you have to wait for an update. You can do nothing, even their apps like Boomerang are broken when currently sharing to Instagram.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I tried so many repost application to be sure about the problem, unfortunately, it seems a bug of the iOS version of Instagram. In our application's Android version, we can trigger the Instagram.